# Sync await NULL reference exception while populating selectlistitem in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, async-await

I am injecting my service in view to populate dropdown in razor like this

```
@inject Web.Services.MyService  Options
```

Now I am trying to populate my dropdown like this

```
<select asp-for="CityID" asp-items="await Options.GetCities();" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option>--Select--</option>
</select>
```

Getcities method is below

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> GetCities()

        {   

            var cities = await _cityrepository.ListAllAsync();

            var items = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Value = null, Text = "All", Selected = true }
            };
            foreach (SetupCities city in cities)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = city.CityId.ToString(), Text = city.Name});
            }

            return items;
        }
```

I am getting following error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
EvolvedX.Web.Services.VMWHService.GetCities() in VMWHService.cs
+
            var cities = await _cityrepository.ListAllAsync();
AspNetCore.Views_Warehouse_CreateWarehouse.ExecuteAsync() in CreateWarehouse.cshtml
+
        <select asp-for="CityID" asp-items="await Options.GetCities();" class="form-control form-control-sm">
```

I can see as the first await hit getcities the function exit. what is the proper way to handle such scenario
M function is exiting before completing the method when it found await that is causing my selectlistitem to be null. I want to know how i modify my code so that selectlistitem get filled null exception will be solved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @SirRufo Not Really my real problem is to handle async method that is causing null reference and in above post no explanation for async found

Comment: Trust me, it does not matter if async or not - something returns null and you have to debug that fact

Comment: M function is exiting before completing the method that is causing my selectlistitem to be null. I want to know how i modify my code so that selectlistitem get filled  null exception will be solved

Comment: Have you registered `MyService` dependency in `Startup`?

Comment: Your `_cityrepository` is null. Check your DI registration.

Comment: Yes my service is registered

Comment: @CodeCaster your tip helped me and issue is solved. Missed _cityrepository assignment in my constructor. if you would have posted answer i will accept that

Comment: @Zia You just stated that this is a perfect duplicate and therefore it does not need to be answered - it was answered a long time ago by the duplicate